# Asp.net Item template null vaue pass in variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using ASP.NET grid view my code is :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" >
<ItemTemplate>
<a target='_blank' href='Details.aspx?uniId=<%#Eval("uniId")%>&uni_name='<%#Eval("uni_name") %>''><%#Eval("uniId")%></a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

server side code is :

```
UniID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uniId"].ToString());
UniName = Request.QueryString["uni_name"].ToString();
```

The problem is that `UniID` variable is working but `UniName` is passing `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around the second call to `Eval`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <a target='_blank' href='Details.aspx?uniId=<%# Eval("uniId") %>&uni_name=<%# Eval("uni_name") %>'><%#Eval("uniId")%></a>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Think about the HTML your code will render, the target for the hyperlink with only consist of `Details.aspx?uniId=someId&uni_name=` no matter what `uni_name` is because the single quote you are trying to encapsulate the value for `uni_name` with end up closing the value for href.